# MySQL error 1287 - On insert into table show the partition deprecated error

Tags: mysql, deprecation-warning, pt-online-schema-change

I am trying to use pt-online-schema-change to alter the schema of some tables on my database. The programs crashs with the MySQL error below.
I need to not throws this kind of errors.
I already tried to put disable-partition-engine-check on the startup of MySQL server.
I am using MySQL version 5.7.21

Error:

```
 Level: Warning
Code: 1287
Message: The partition engine, used by table 'nokia_oss_stats_4g_timbrasil_dum._lte_cell_avail_new', is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use native partitioning instead.
Query: INSERT LOW_PRIORITY IGNORE INTO `nokia_oss_stats_4g_timbrasil_dum`.`_lte_cell_avail_new` (`period_start_time`, `dateday`, `period_duration`, `dn_plmn`, `dn_mrbts`, `dn_lnbts`, `dn_lncel`, `dn_mcc`, `dn_mnc`, `m8020c0`, `m8020c1`, `m8020c10`, `m8020c11`, `m8020c12`, `m8020c2`, `m8020c3`, `m8020c4`, `m8020c5`, `m8020c6`, `m8020c7`, `m8020c8`, `m8020c9`, `netchart_count`) SELECT `period_start_time`, `dateday`, `period_duration`, `dn_plmn`, `dn_mrbts`, `dn_lnbts`, `dn_lncel`, `dn_mcc`, `dn_mnc`, `m8020c0`, `m8020c1`, `m8020c10`, `m8020c11`, `m8020c12`, `m8020c2`, `m8020c3`, `m8020c4`, `m8020c5`, `m8020c6`, `m8020c7`, `m8020c8`, `m8020c9`, `netchart_count` FROM `nokia_oss_stats_4g_timbrasil_dum`.`lte_cell_avail` FORCE INDEX(`PRIMARY`) WHERE ((`dateday` > ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` > ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` > ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` > ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` > ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` = ? AND `dn_mcc` > ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` = ? AND `dn_mcc` = ? AND `dn_mnc` > ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` = ? AND `dn_mcc` = ? AND `dn_mnc` = ? AND `period_start_time` >= ?)) AND ((`dateday` < ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` < ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` < ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` < ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` < ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` = ? AND `dn_mcc` < ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` = ? AND `dn_mcc` = ? AND `dn_mnc` < ?) OR (`dateday` = ? AND `dn_plmn` = ? AND `dn_mrbts` = ? AND `dn_lnbts` = ? AND `dn_lncel` = ? AND `dn_mcc` = ? AND `dn_mnc` = ? AND `period_start_time` <= ?)) LOCK IN SHARE MODE
```

Comment: From this [Note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html), In MySQL 5.7.21 and later, you must use `--disable-partition-engine-check=false`, is that what you've tried ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that on my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this warnings in your program and not stop it. If this is 3rd part program then you should change settings in MySQL  and turn off STRICT mode and disable deprecated messages.

You can edit my.cnf file and add to section mysqld empty value for sql_mode

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the strict mode using giving query run on terminal or phpmyadmin query-

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Actually, my.cnf is like:
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
And the warning is still throwing